# Switching columns to last column in data frame r

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with 20 columns. I want to save 20 dataframes where each column is one time the last column. How can I do this efficiently with for example this dataframe?

```
dataframe <- data.frame(a=numeric(),
                        b=numeric(),
                        c=numeric(),
                        d=numeric(),
                        e=numeric(),
                        f=numeric())
```

Comment: Why do you want to copy the data.frame for this? Just reorder as needed when you need it.

Comment: Because if I have to do it twenty times its a lot of work and i need to export if, to use it in another software program

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i in 1:20) {
  write.csv(DF, paste0(i, ".csv"))
  DF <- DF[,c(2:20,1)]
}
```